# Logical Mathematical Game - Finding values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

Well this question from the Russian mathematical olympiad (I am interested in this question because of its level to solve)

2 friends Tom and Peter play a game as follows: Peter read to Tom writes the numbers from 1 to 8 (each number is written once) in the order that Peter wants. Tom writes them down on a piece of paper, adding each digit, Starting from the 2nd number, write to the left or right of all the given numbers written. The result on a piece of paper has a 9-digit number. Tom wants the number to be written down as large as possible, Peter wants it to be as small as possible. Ask for the number what is the gain if both play very well.

Comment: Incomprehensible.

Comment: I think the game is this:  Peter says the numbers 1 through 8 in some order.  Tom writes them down in that order, but he gets to choose at each step whether to write the digit on the left or on the right of those digits already written down.  Peter chooses his order to make the resulting 8-digit number small.  Tom chooses left and right to make the number large.  If they both play perfectly, I guess there's a unique final answer.

Comment: Play the game with only the digits 1, 2, 3.  There's no way Peter can stop Tom from making the leftmost digit 3.  So the final number is either 312 or 321.  Peter can force 312 by using the order 1, 3, 2.   So in this case the answer is 312.  The answer to your question is a number starting with 81.

Comment: @B.G, sounds good. But explain to me how anyone can write the numbers from one to eight, using each once, and end up with a nine-digit number.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Take the limit as 8 approaches 9.